My CocoaPods pod cannot be found via Cocoapods website search
I have a number of Cocoapods that are available on the Cocoapods website, but they cannot be found via the CocoaPods website search
For example, my repo TinyCSV https://cocoapods.org/pods/TinyCSV
If I try to search for this pod via the website (eg. using the search term tinycsv) it cannot be found.
If I search via the command line, it finds the latest version
% pod search tinycsv
-> TinyCSV (1.2.0)
   A tiny Swift CSV decoder/encoder library
   pod 'TinyCSV', '~> 1.2.0'
   - Homepage: https://github.com/dagronf
   - Source:   https://github.com/dagronf/TinyCSV.git
   - Versions: 1.2.0, 1.1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.6.1 [trunk repo]

I have a number of cocoapods repos that all have the same issue so I'm pretty sure that it is something that I'm overlooking but I haven't been able to track it down.
Can anyone help?
